# Issue with Configuring Zuul For Reverse Proxy just for serving content

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have embedded the Zuul Proxy into a Spring Boot Application where I use the PreFilter to authenticate request and forward to another Spring Boot Service, which serves content on the basis of timestamp. The content service varies the data size based on the timestamp sent by the client.

Couple of issues being faced:

- The Zuul is slowing down the service significantly. When I did performance testing for 25 Hits per sec using zuul in the front, the It gave 4 TPS. However when I removed the zuul as the layer and directly hit the content service with the same scenario I got 32 TPS, which is a huge difference.
- Looking at the Ribbon Client it looks to me that it is Using RestTemplate and receiving the content and again returning to the client.
- The issue in this approach is that if the content is already served as Compressed, Ribbon is uncompressing and and sending it as compressed back to the client which is a overhead.

I did not find any configuration on Zuul to work purely as a Reverse proxy where in apart from applying filter it should stream the content as is from the forwarding service rather than storing and then returning to the client.

Could anyone help here if they know how to configure Zuul in this scenario?

Due to this performance issue I'm forced to take the authentication layer within content service in order to achieve the best performance.